# Android Time UTC

Tags: java, android, date, datetime

I am working on an Android app that frequently travels from Time Zone to TZ. I am getting various errors with times and TZs. The latest error is, when I load the flat file with times (see below), everything looks good. When I save the app environment (aka all variables/objects to sharedprefs), stop and then restart the app the time displayed is no longer local but UTC.

I began developing the app just using the default/local TZ. However, this became very complicated with DST and various TZs. Therefore my current approach is to store time in the app in UTC, and calculate differences between UTC times as needed. Then convert the UTC-stored time to the local TZ on-demand for user interaction.

I recognize there are many posts related to android time. I think I have read most if not all on java.util.date and Joda. However, I am still stuck. So, here goes...

I have 3 sources of time for the app. 1) I read in UTC Strings from a flat file 2) I get milliseconds since the Epoch for system time stamp (in UTC). 3) I get UTC in a string via a rest API. The app does numerous calculations between the 3 categories such as time difference, add time, etc. Below I will post my code for each of these

1 - Convert string UTCs that come from a file

```
public static Date string2date(String strformat, String strdate){
    Date tdate = timestamp();
    TimeZone tz  = TimeZone.getDefault() ;
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(strformat);
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    String dateInString = strdate;
    try {
        tdate = formatter.parse(dateInString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return tdate;
}
```

2 - Get milliseconds since Epoch

```
public static Date timestamp() {
    Calendar localCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
    //Date currentTime = localCalendar.getTime();
    Date currentTime = GetUTCdatetimeAsDate();
    return currentTime;
    public static Date GetUTCdatetimeAsDate()
    {
        //note: doesn't check for null
        return StringDateToDate(GetUTCdatetimeAsString());
    }

    public static String GetUTCdatetimeAsString()
    {
        final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(longdt);
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        final String utcTime = sdf.format(new Date());
        return utcTime;
    }

    public static Date StringDateToDate(String StrDate)
    {
        Date dateToReturn = null;
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(longdt);
        try
        {
            dateToReturn = (Date)dateFormat.parse(StrDate);
        }
        catch (ParseException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dateToReturn;
    }
```

3 - Get UTC in a string via a rest API (Format is "2017-02-10T01:09:00Z")

```
try {
    Calendar tempCal = ISO8601.toCalendar(dateLocal);
    Log.e (" fbu "," fsutc " + tempCal.getTime() );
    ISODepDate = tempCal.getTime();
    tempCal = ISO8601.toCalendar(dateLocal2);
    ISOArrDate = tempCal.getTime();
    //ab.setTimeZone(PST);
    Log.e (" fbu "," fsutc " + dateLocal + " / " + dateLocal2);
    Log.e (" fbu "," fsutc " + ISODepDate + " / " + ISOArrDate);
}
catch (Exception a){
    int aa = 1;
    Log.e (" exception "," a " + a);
}

public static Calendar toCalendar(final String iso8601string)
        throws ParseException {
    Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    TimeZone tz  = TimeZone.getDefault() ;
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    String s = iso8601string.replace(".000Z", "+00:00");
    try {
        s = s.substring(0, 22) + s.substring(23);  // to get rid of the ":"
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        throw new ParseException("Invalid length", 0);
    }
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").parse(s);
    calendar.setTime(date);
    return calendar;
}
```

4 - Finally, here is what I am using to "Display" the above 3 time categories in local time.

```
public String UTCtoLocal(Date indate, Boolean formatLong) {
    Date utcDate = indate;
    String result;
    //Log.e( " utc "," indate " + indate);
    /*utcDate = your own initialization here;*/
    Date localDate = new Date(utcDate.getTime() + TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset());
    //Log.e( " utc "," localdate " + localDate);
    if (formatLong){
        result = longd.format(localDate);
    } else {
        result = shortt.format(localDate);
    }
    return result;
```

The questions are, given the expectation that I store in UTC and display in Local, a) Have I implemented items 1-4 correctly? b) Will the above code actually store the times in UTC and display in local?

After flat file load everything looks good. After restart the times are displayed in UTC vs Local.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Thanks yes, at the bottom of my post.

Comment: @FrankZappa, did you encounter any problem with your code? The best person to verify your code is working is you...

Comment: You could use JUnit Tests to check if your code works properly...

Comment: For the question A, please use JUnit or other unit-testing framework to test your code; for the question B, yes. `java.util.Date` or `java.util.Calendar` do not handle time zone, they store values in UTC. Personally, I prefer `ZonedDateTime` from package `java.time` (available since Java 8)